# Java Libraray to produce plain text markdown or asciidoc

Tags: library, java, markdown

There's a lot of libraries to render markdown file. But I cannot found any library to produce a `*.md` file from Java code. I'm looking for some library like:

```
FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream("readme.md");
MarkdownDocument doc = new MarkdownDocument(outStream);
doc.appendHeader1("Welcome", HeaderStyle.UNDERLINE);
doc.appendParagraph("A paragraph...");
doc.flush();
```

And the above code would produce the following content:

```
Welcome
=======

A paragraph...
```

**Update**

Actually, either markdown or asciidoc library is OK. I'm building a testing tool, which will need to generate report. To support both Word, PDF and HTML formats, I want to produce plain text report first, then use Pandoc to convert it into the desired format.

Hope that the update make my intension more clear for a better recomnendation.

Comment: I would expect that pretty much any markdown parser would also include "writer" methods, so [MarkdownPapers](http://markdown.tautua.org) would be a good place to look.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have looked in [pegdown](https://github.com/sirthias/pegdown), [commonmark-java](https://github.com/atlassian/commonmark-java), [txtmark](https://github.com/rjeschke/txtmark) and MarkdownPapers. None of them matches my requirement.

Comment: They don't have write methods?   I'm surprised.  How long can you wait for a jar?

Comment: Next Friday is my deadline for the report generating feature. So, I've planned to implement the library myself. Just some basic features, enough for the case. But if you also want to do that, I'm happy to give my contribution. 

For the first question, the rendering libraries only support for custom renderer from the AST after parse the input markdown.

Comment: Next Friday is too close for me to be certain I can help you.  Good luck with your project.

Comment: I would very much like to see what you create - I've been looking at this, and providing a creation api for markdown seems like a nontrivial task.  For one thing, there's multiple flavors.  But it's an interesting and worthwhile effort, so if you'd like to share, I'd like to see it.

Comment: @CPerkins, you're right. It's non trivival task. I've planned to make a library that will produce CommonMark document. But then, I need the internal reference feature of Pandoc Markdown and Github table. I've ended up write simple util class with some methods for header and table. It's work for my project. But I don't think it's worth as a library.

Comment: I'd come to the same conclusion about just a wrapper for creating markdown (non-trivial effort, trivial benefit).   But I'm not entirely done with the concept.  I've been noodling around with the idea of an interface which promises that a class can render itself as markdown (maybe also one for html), containing very simple methods (e.g., `toMarkdown(flavor)`).  Still non-trivial effort, but now it's a less-trivial benefit.  But in general, this feels like something that needs to grow organically from need.  Good luck with your project.

Comment: https://github.com/Steppschuh/Java-Markdown-Generator

Comment: @Amitabha, my question predated the github project you mentioned. But I'll accept it if you can post it as an Answer.